# Cygwin is executing commands very slowly on XP. What could it be?

Tags: performance, bash, windows-xp, cygwin

My question is similar to

- [Why does Cygwin execute shell commands very slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811435/why-does-cygwin-execute-shell-commands-very-slowly)
- [Cygwin's bash became extremely slow after errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533806/cygwins-bash-became-extremely-slow-after-errors)

I think my problem is caused by a different issue though.

Here is an example of extremely slow commands in Cygwin:

```
time for i in {1..10} ; do bash -c "echo Hello" ; done

Hello
...

real    0m21.588s
user    0m0.458s
sys     0m0.989s
```

Something is causing this... but what could it be?

Things that I have tried:

- Disabling windows firewall and windows security essentials.
- I don't have any other antivirus products.
- I tried killing different user processes to see if any of them could be interfering - no luck.
- I'm not connected to any network.
- If I run the commands in `C:\cygwin\bin` via windows `CMD`, e.g. `C:\cygwin\bin\ls.exe`, they are *still* slow.

I then tried running this command to get a better idea of what's going on:

```
strace -o bash.strace bash -c "echo hello"
```

From what I can see there is one row that was taking 90% of the time:

(in case it's not clear it is the row starting with 1028210 - I included the other rows for context)

```
  5       5 [main] bash 1088 open_shared: name shared.5, n 5, shared 0x60FB0000 (wanted 0x60FB0000), h 0x74C
208     213 [main] bash 1088 heap_init: heap base 0x530000, heap top 0x530000
118     331 [main] bash 1088 open_shared: name S-1-5-21-2025429265-1957994488-1801674531-1003.1, n 1, shared 0x60FC0000 (wanted 0x60FC0000), h 0x748
 85     416 [main] bash 1088 user_info::create: opening user shared for 'S-1-5-21-2025429265-1957994488-1801674531-1003' at 0x60FC0000
 83     499 [main] bash 1088 user_info::create: user shared version 6112AFB3
344     843 [main] bash 1088 dll_crt0_0: finished dll_crt0_0 initialization
283    1126 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: wait 0xFFFFFFFF
 87    1213 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: removed 0x23CE64 element 0
104    1317 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: wait 0xFFFFFFFF
 70    1387 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: removed 0x23CE64 element 0
102    1489 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: wait 0xFFFFFFFF
 70    1559 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: removed 0x23CE64 element 0
110    1669 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: wait 0xFFFFFFFF
 70    1739 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: removed 0x23CE64 element 0
781    2520 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: wait 0xFFFFFFFF
 76    2596 [main] bash 1088 _cygtls::remove: removed 0x23CE64 element 0
278    2874 [sig] bash 1088 wait_sig: entering ReadFile loop, my_readsig 0x72C, my_sendsig 0x728
1028210 1031084 [main] bash 1088 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\cygwin\home\Adam, no-keep-rel, no-add-slash)
107 1031191 [main] bash 1088 normalize_win32_path: C:\cygwin\home\Adam = normalize_win32_path (C:\cygwin\home\Adam)
 59 1031250 [main] bash 1088 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /home/Adam = conv_to_posix_path (C:\cygwin\home\Adam)
11535 1042785 [main] bash 1088 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 0: not open
 69 1042854 [main] bash 1088 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 1: not open
 62 1042916 [main] bash 1088 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 2: not open
360 1043276 [main] bash (1088) open_shared: name cygpid.1088, n 1088, shared 0x60FE0000 (wanted 0x60FE0000), h 0x678
 65 1043341 [main] bash 1088 **********************************************
 46 1043387 [main] bash 1088 Program name: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe (pid 1088, ppid 1)
 46 1043433 [main] bash 1088 App version:  1007.7, api: 0.230
 45 1043478 [main] bash 1088 DLL version:  1007.9, api: 0.237
 46 1043524 [main] bash 1088 DLL build:    2011-03-29 10:10
 51 1043575 [main] bash 1088 OS version:   Windows NT-5.1
 45 1043620 [main] bash 1088 Heap size:    402653184
 45 1043665 [main] bash 1088 **********************************************
 45 1043710 [main] bash 1088 pinfo::thisproc: myself->dwProcessId 1088
 50 1043760 [main] bash 1088 time: 1321506515 = time (0)
862 1044622 [main] bash 1088 parse_options: glob (called func)
 78 1044700 [main] bash 1088 parse_options: returning
 45 1044745 [main] bash 1088 environ_init: GetEnvironmentStrings returned 0x10000
 ...
```

I don't really understand what problem the offending line could be alluding to:

```
mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\cygwin\home\Adam, no-keep-rel, no-add-slash)
```

How can I debug this issue further? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since updating to the latest Cygwin (v2.769), this is much less of an issue. (Previously I was using v2.738 I think)

Under 2.769, the same command gives much better results:

```
$ time for i in {1..10} ; do bash -c "echo Hello" ; done
Hello
...

real    0m0.641s
user    0m0.379s
sys     0m0.506s
```

Cygwin is still slower than I would like - I mainly use it for git and vim, and both of those are much slower than their native counterparts.

But it is at least much more usable now.

Comment: +1 for the simple command I could use to benchmark my own upgrade! (0.67s -> 0.37s going from DLL version 1.7.1 -> 1.7.18)

Comment: where is the version: `v2.769`? I just found `v1.7.27` on the official site

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an identical scenario:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-08/msg00080.html

It couldn't hurt to add your post to the Cygwin trouble reports list.  Perhaps you could also post on the Cygwin forums.

Comment: One other possibility to consider is running Linux as a Virtual Machine on your XP PC.  For example, download VMWare player (http://www.vmware.com) and an Ubuntu appliance (http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/)

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll see if I can get any info from the Cygwin people. I would like to use a VM. I'm not sure I can at my work place though. In the past I did have an Ubuntu appliance, but had to remove it as management claimed it was not secure.